# Routing between two subnets. (Need Solution)

Tags: linux, file-sharing

Need help according to scenario given:

Client end PCs: 400 + 
Network :

Server 1 (Linux) : 192.168.2.0/24 (For Application, Internet not working) GW: 192.168.2.1 Clients: 192.168.2.1 - 254
Server 2 (Linux) : 192.168.3.0/24 (For Internet users) GW: 192.168.3.1 Clients: 192.168.3.2 - 254

Server 2 is connected to DSL Broadband. Server 1 and Server 2 both are on same physical network i.e. Same switches.

Current issue:
                         i have to deploy a file and print server but this server will be accessed by both (192.168.2.x and 192.168.3.x) one same workgroup. as both subnets are on same switched network.

Limitations:
                         Currently there is no hardware routers and firewall. Need to complete this task with Linux / Windows / AD.

Tested / Worked so far:
                 Configured one PC with two NIC's With the IPS:
NIC 1 : 192.168.3.2 GW: 192.168.3.1 Subnet: 255.255.255.0
NIC 2 : 192.168.2.2 GW: Empty Subnet: 255.255.255.0

Kindly provide any solution what should i do to get sharing enable on both Subnets.

Thank you All

Comment: Both subnets are on the same switched network i.e. the same broadcast domain?  I hope not if you really want to keep them isolated.

Comment: Why not just bind dual IP's to both hosts if they are in the same broadcast domain?

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like you're just digging yourself further into a hole with this brittle network design.  You're talking about Active Directory, but yet you mention a workgroup?  And all the machines on the same switch (broadcast domain) but different subnet? And no firewall?  Yikes.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done in terms of the dual-NIC PC should work fine except you've set a default gateway on both NICs, any given machine should just have one DG - that's why it's the default. Also have you really set your servers to work on x.x.x.0 static IPs? if so why, I know it *can* work but that's a reserved address to denote the entire subnet - I'd move them to a 1-254 range right away, it could certainly cause routing problems - if I've misinterpreted your information please just update it.

I do have another question, for server 1 it's DG is the start of your client range (i.e. x.x.x.1), is that right? it sounds odd, is that what you really wanted to do?

Comment: Dear Chopper you miss judged my issue. I have mentioned x.x.x.x/0 just for an example. my pool is 192.168.2.1 - 254 and 192.168.3.1 - 254
and for your question... Yes default gateways for both the subnet clients is 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.3.1... and thats bcz.. i am assigning IP's linearly to further apply policies on them in small subnets using squid. I.e. 192.168.2.10 to 192.168.2.18 are blocked for internet and so on....

Answer (score 0):

"Current issue: i have to deploy a file and print server but this server will be accessed by both (192.168.2.x and 192.168.3.x)"

"Limitations: Currently there is no hardware routers and firewall."

A: 
You need a router...and you should probably use a firewall if you have clients accessing the internet.  The Gateway IPs on each subnet (x.x.x.1)...do they actually exist on any device in your network?  What you might be able to do is set the gateway IPs on your subnets to the PC with multiple NICs and have it act as the router between subnets, but if you have 400 clients and want to start divvying up the network into subnets, you should probably just get a hardware router...

Answer (score 0):

I would use Vyatta Core [located here](http://www.vyatta.com/downloads/index.php), it is a free router, it is based on Linux and is easy to install and configure.    All you would need is a host with with two nics if your switch supports VLANs and trunks or 3 nics (.2, .3, DSL connection) if not.